# Замена элементов на нули в матрице

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ребята, прошу помочь в решении данной задачи: "Задана действительная матрица размером n*m. Написать программу, позволяющую заменить все элементы, наименьшие в
строке, на нули". В матрицах довольно плох, заранее благодарю всех за ответ!

```
from random import randint
rows = int(input('Введите количество строк: '))
cols = int(input('Введите количество столбцов: '))

matrixA = [[randint(0, 100) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
matrixB = [[randint(0, 100) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]

print('Первая матрица:', matrixA)
print("Вторая матрица: ", matrixB)
```

Код неполный и явно требует доработок. Можно сделать без рандома.

Comment: Как даётся матрица ?

Comment: На любой вкус и цвет) Условие задачи полное

Comment: ваши попытки, идеи? матрицы - самая основа основ, если у вас возникают с ними сложности..

Comment: from random import randint
    rows = int(input('Введите количество строк: '))
    cols = int(input('Введите количество столбцов: '))

    matrixA = [[randint(0, 100) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
    matrixB = [[randint(0, 100) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]

    print('Первая матрица:', matrixA)
    print("Вторая матрица: ", matrixB)

Answer (score 0):

```
from random import randint
rows = int(input('Введите количество строк: '))
cols = int(input('Введите количество столбцов: '))
matrixA = [[randint(0, 100) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
matrixB = [[randint(0, 100) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)]
print('Первая матрица:', matrixA)
print("Вторая матрица: ", matrixB)

for row in range(rows):
    el=min(matrixA[row])
    while el in matrixA[row]:
        ind=matrixA[row].index(el)
        matrixA[row][ind]=0
    el=min(matrixB[row])
    while el in matrixB[row]:
        ind=matrixB[row].index(el)
        matrixB[row][ind]=0

print('\nПеределанные матрицы\n')
print('Первая матрица:', matrixA)
print("Вторая матрица: ", matrixB)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

rows = int(input('Введите количество строк: ')) #Строки
cols= int(input('Введите количество столбцов: ')) #Столбцы
matrixA=[[random.randint(0,100) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(rows)] #Генератор  матрицы
B = []
for i in range(0,rows):
    print(matrixA[i])
    print(sum(matrixA[i]))
    B+=[sum(matrixA[i])]
    print(B)
print(B.index(min(B)))
matrixB = [[random.randint(0,0) for j in range(cols)] for i in range(1)]
for i in range (0, cols):
    matrixA[B.index(min(B))] = matrixB
print(matrixA)
input('\n\nНажмите Enter для выхода')
```

Ответ на мой вопрос. Возможно будет кому-то полезен. Спасибо всем за ответы!